# how to get cross-domain javascript response text

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, response

I have a big size js in domain a.exmaple.com, in page b.example.com need this js.

As the js size is 300kb more, I want to use localStorage to storage it.

Now is the problem, I can't get the js text, in page b.exmaple.com, I use 
a script tag link the js,so the script.innerHTML is ''.

If I use the xhr get the response.text, it will cross domain.

And it's may hard make the js set response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'b.example.com'.

Comment: You can simply add a `script` targeting your script file at `a.example.com`. 300 KB isn't that much to bother about it. And, most importantly, browser caches script files - it will not load it again every time.

Comment: For it's a mobile page, when the network speed is not good enough , the script may loads more than 3 seconds,  it's too long. And as I know ,the cache in mobile is not good as the pc client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than avoiding download of js files, try to enable [deflate options](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/apache-web-server/data-compression-using-the-mod-deflate-module) in your web server

If this is not an option, you can structure your js file as a JSON, something like

```
function classname(){}
classname.method = function(){}..
```

Now once you have downloaded, simply do JSON.stringify(className) and store it in your localstorage

Comment: it's an idea, is there some idea can get the response text not modify the script itself?

Comment: @SantinoDu yes, but for that server from where you are fetching this script needs to facilitate the cross domain/origin calls as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS